# VB form load event based on date

Tags: vb.net

I'm attempting to display a button on a secondary form in vb based on what the date is (Trying to get a reset button to show only on the last day of the year).

I've tried a few different things with the code below...

I originally put it in the Form Load Event of Form 2, no msgbox displayed, button didn't display.

I cut the code out of my project and pasted it into the Form Load Event of a new project to test it on it's own... Msgbox displayed and button displayed!! :)

This got me thinking maybe I had to put the code into the Form Load Event of the Main Form. I pasted it there and made the modifications to point to form2 (Current version of the code)....

Once again , no msgbox, no button

What am I missing?

```
Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim date1 As String = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
    Dim todaysdate As String = Format(Now, "Long Date")
    Dim dayofweek = todaysdate.Substring(0, todaysdate.IndexOf(","))
    Dim year As String = Now.Year
    Dim datecheck As String = "12/29/"
    Dim datecheck1 As String = "12/30/"
    Dim datecheck2 As String = "12/31/"

    ' Add Current Year to Date to Check variables
    datecheck = datecheck + year
    datecheck1 = datecheck1 + year
    datecheck2 = datecheck2 + year


    Dim expenddt As Date = Date.ParseExact(date1, date1, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)

    Dim expenddt1 As Date = Date.ParseExact(datecheck, datecheck,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)

    Dim expenddt2 As Date = Date.ParseExact(datecheck1, datecheck1,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)

    Dim expenddt3 As Date = Date.ParseExact(datecheck2, datecheck2,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)


    ' If DEC 29 or 30 Falls Fiday, Display Reset Button
    If date1 = datecheck And dayofweek = "Friday" Then
        ' MsgBox Used Only For Testing
        MsgBox("THIS ONE WORKED!")
        Form2.Reset.Visible = True
    End If

    If date1 = datecheck1 And dayofweek = "Friday" Then
        ' MsgBox Used Only For Testing
        MsgBox("THIS ONE WORKED!!")
        Form2.Reset.Visible = True
    End If


    ' If it's Dec 31 and it's Not Saturday or Sunday, Display Reset Button
    If date1 = datecheck2 and dayofweek <> "Saturday" and dayofweek <> "Sunday" Then
        ' MsgBox Used Only For Testing
        MsgBox("THIS ONE WORKED!!!")
        Form2.Reset.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: put breakpoints in your code and you'll find out where it's happening

Comment: I'm not sure this is the whole of the problem, but I'll tell you one thing: passing the date string itself to `ParseExact`'s format parameter is precisely wrong and quite useless. Instead, pass an actual custom format string per `String.Format` etc. Once you've fixed those three calls, see if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, have a read through the documentation for the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) structure. You can do everything that you're trying to do without using Strings. The `DateTime` structure has a `DayOfWeek` property, and `Month` and `Day` properties that will help you here.

Secondly, the way you are using the `ParseExact` method is wrong (not that you should end up using it). The second parameter to the `ParseExact` method is the format string that you expect the date to be in (something like "MM/dd/yyyy"). Passing in a formatted date will not work, and from my experiments, will simply return the current date without any parsing occurring.

So, with all that in mind (and assuming you want to show the button on the last *weekday* in the year as your code suggests, and not just the last *day* in the year as your question stated), try something like this:

```
Private Sub Main_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Form2.Reset.Visible = ShouldShowResetButton(DateTime.Now)
End Sub


Private Function ShouldShowResetButton(currentDate As DateTime) As Boolean
    Return GetLastWeekdayInYear(currentDate.Year) = currentDate.Date
End Function


Private Function GetLastWeekdayInYear(year As Integer) As Date
    Dim lastDayInYear As Date


    lastDayInYear = New Date(year, 12, 31)

    Select Case lastDayInYear.DayOfWeek
        Case DayOfWeek.Sunday
            Return New Date(year, 12, 29)

        Case DayOfWeek.Saturday
            Return New Date(year, 12, 30)

        Case Else
            Return lastDayInYear

    End Select
End Function
```